# nginx rewrite faux image to PHP

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Working on using nginx to serve images.

static.foobar.com/UUID.jpg url will actually serve as a pointer to a PHP script which determines if you have permission to view that image (and if so, serve it via PHP/X-Accel-Redirect).

DNS/nginx are setup correctly on the subdomain, but I'm getting a 404. Here's my current server block:

```
server {
    listen x.x.x.x:80;

    server_name static.foobar.com;

    location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png) {
        internal;
        rewrite "^/([a-f0-9]{8})-([a-f0-9]{4})-4([a-f0-9]{3})-([a-f0-9]{4})-([a-f0-9]{12}).(gif|jpg|png)" /dir/photo.php?uuid=$1-$2-4$3-$4-$5 last;
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if the presence of gif|jpg|png is forcing nginx to set the mime-type as an image, which is causing a conflict when I send the session to a PHP file. Could that be the issue? What else can I do to help debug this or does anyone have any pointers please?

Thanks kindly

---

Update: in the end, the problem was that on my server, nginx php-fpm is not supported with cpanel, so my nginx config wasn't able to run php at all. I was hoping to offload serving of these files via nginx but will unfortunately have to go back to using apache. Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: Do you have a location for processing PHP scripts in your `server` block?

Comment: The handler for `/dir/photo.php` is the one to mark `internal` - if appropriate.

Comment: thank you both very much for the pointers. The problem turned out to be something unrelated (updated my post).

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

One issue here is at least that you are using the `internal` keyword inside the location. This means that it will match only requests coming from inside nginx, for example from other `location` blocks. You should remove that keyword.

Your regexes need also other fixes. Try this `location` block:

```
location ~ \.(gif|jpg|png)$ {
    rewrite "^/([a-f0-9]{8})-([a-f0-9]{4})-4([a-f0-9]{3})-([a-f0-9]{4})-([a-f0-9]{12})\.(gif|jpg|png)$" /dir/photo.php?uuid=$1-$2-4$3-$4-$5 last;
}
```

Comment: Not an error/issue but that rewrite rule can be simplified a little - since there's no need for a capturing group for each bit of the uuid, to then rebuild the uuid. i.e. it can be written with only one capturing group: `rewrite "^/([a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12})\.(?:gif|jpg|png)$" /dir/photo.php?$1;`

Comment: Thank you Tero. I was going by the x-accel-redirect docs on nginx and it suggested the use of `internal`. I was not aware of this restriction. Thank you also, AD7six, that is far more palatable. :)